# Firebase Not Capturing Email/Phone from Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

When a user logs into the app using Facebook, I am able to capture and display their full name; however, neither email nor phone number is coming across. I have tried both the "One account per email address" as well as "Multiple accounts per email". I have tested it with an account whose email address is definitely not already registered in Firebase. What am I missing such that email/phone are not being captured? This all does work with Google accounts.

```
let name = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName    // works!
let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email         // nil- why?
let phone = Auth.auth().currentUser?.phoneNumber   // nil -why?
```

The login process, which is standard Firebase w/ Facebook, looks like this:

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!)
{
    if let error = error
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    else
    {
        if FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil
        {
            let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
                if let error = error
                {
                    print (error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To update based on comments below. The following also produces a nil email and phone when inspecting the contents of userInfo. I understand the phone might just be that way, but it seems the email was supposed to work.

```
let userInfo = Auth.auth().currentUser?.providerData
```

Comment: May be that Facebook user has not allowed access to email or phone number

Comment: @ArpitJain I am using my own account and it does allow access.

Answer (score 0):

The top level phoneNumber `currentUser.phoneNumber` is only for Firebase verified phone numbers. If you have that Facebook phone number, you can use the currentUser.updatePhoneNumber API to verify that number (you will need to go through the whole flow). Otherwise, you can wait for the upcoming Admin node.js API to set phone numbers with Admin privileges on existing users: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/commit/68563c4b2c8128fbc45fc65bad3f6730d320b539

As for the email, in the case of "multiple accounts per email" you need to set it yourself via `currentUser.updateEmail`. You can get the Facebook email from `currentUser.providerData` which contains the Facebook provider data.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. With regards to the email address, it is nil within providerData. Other fields are not such as photoURL, but with Facebook the email remain nil (it is fine with Google). I am also not allowing multiple accounts per email.

Comment: Can you try with a different Facebook account? It could be that this account doesn't allow access for these fields. I know you claim otherwise, but it doesn't hurt to test another account just to check whether this issue is isolated to that specific account.

Comment: I have tested it with two different accounts. Same issue.